# sending files using slash commands discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to send a file using slash commands in discord.py. But the bot won't send said file after said command is used

Here is the code I attempted to use:
`@bot.tree.command(name="lcm", description="Love Cherry Motion") async def lcm(interaction: discord.Interaction): file_to_send = discord.File("LoveCherryMotion.mp4") await interaction.response.send_message(file=discord.File(file_to_send))`

But this was error came up instead
[error after running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGs8l.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are using the already `File` class assigned variable `file_to_send` inside the `file=discord.File(file_to_send)`.

It's a simple fix just replace your `file=discord.File(file_to_send)` with `file=file_to_send`

So, overall your code should look like this:-

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="lcm", description="Love Cherry Motion")
async def lcm(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    file_to_send = discord.File("LoveCherryMotion.mp4")
    await interaction.response.send_message(file=file_to_send)
```